# Why am I getting a "Cannot find module" err when compiling Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am just getting started using typescript on the server and I'm pretty much stuck trying to import 3rd party npm modules.  Here is what I have declared:

```
import mongodb = require('mongodb');
import assert = require('assert');
import Q  = require('q');
```

... and I am getting the following errors when compiling:

```
src/Databse.ts(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mongodb'.
src/Databse.ts(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'assert'.
src/Databse.ts(3,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'q'.
```

What is the correct way to import 3rd party modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't feel the correct way to import 3rd party's library. You can simply use only import

```
import "library";
```

OR

```
import {module} from "library";
```

> Note:- when you are using above syntax then you need to make your that
>   the module you are importing exist otherwise you will get the error
>   that it can't find the module you are trying to import.

If you want to use webpack then

```
require("library");
```

Or like this

```
var module = require("library");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the typing declarations ?

```
typings install mongodb --save
typings install dt~assert --save
typings install dt~q --save
```

Then you will need to reference the typings.
Either using the triple slash-directive

```
/// <reference path="..." />
```

More about it here [Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Or add the typings index.d.ts file in files array in tsconfig.json

```
"files": [
    "./typings/index.d.ts",
  ]
```